# Issue with Webquiz and MikTeX in Windows 10

Tags: miktex, winedt, python, webquiz

I'm using WinEdt 9.1 on Windows 10. I'm trying to use Webquiz package, but I can't compile. Webquiz did not succeed because MikTeX could not find the script engine 'python.exe'.

I already installed Python 3.8.3 on my computer, and I have the same issue.

What can I do so that MikTeX could find the script engine 'python.exe'?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that Python is in your system's PATH variable. Open a command line, type `python` and press enter. Do you get an error? Then Python is not in the search path, which is why `webquiz` can't find it.